# Latex : Extra page remove

Tags: report, latex

I am new to LaTeX. I have no idea about it at all and I am facing a problem. When writing a report the NEW CHAPTER always starts with odd page causing an empty page on my report. How can I remove it? I have read other answers on stackoverflow but could not make out what to be done.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{times} 
\begin{document} 
%\pagestyle{empty} 
\input{first} 
\pagestyle{plain} 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\newpage 
\input{declaration} 
\newpage 
\input{acknowledgement} 
\newpage 
\input{abstract} 
\tableofcontents 
\listoffigures 
\input{chapter1} 
\include{chapter2} 
\include{chapter3} 
\include{conclusion} 
\include{references} 
\pagestyle{plain} 
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References} 
\end{document}
```

first.tex

```
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
   Some title text
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\input{first}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newpage
\input{declaration}
\newpage
\input{acknowledgement}
\newpage
\input{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\input{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{conclusion}
\include{references}
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\end{document}
This is the main page. :)

Comment: From what i can see,its all expanded only :/

Comment: The problem was not before.I started using begin{flushleft} in each chapter.Can it be a problem?

Comment: To open the chapter on any page (not strictly an odd page), add `openany` to your `\documentclass` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved my problem. What i did was i remove `\begin{flushleft}` from all the chapters and used `RaggedRight` at the main tex file.

Answer (score 18):

use this for deleting blankpage

```
\let\clearpage\relax
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know where the issue is. Remove the

```
\newpage
```

after

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: One of the other `\include` files has a `\section` that creates the section header. Where is it and how does it look like? (I have to go to bed right now...)

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing book use \documentclass[10pta4paper,openany]{book}, in the start of document it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the `report` class is onesided by default - this "will definitely" **not** "solve your problem"